# Entity Framework Core eager loading by navigation name(string)

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I have 2 entity classes as below:

```
public class Office
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public int CityId { get; set; }

    public City City { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ProvinceId { get; set; }

    public Province Province { get; set; }
}
```

I know I can include City in these ways:

```
IQueryable<Office> offices = _context.Offices.Include(o => o.City);

//or

IQueryable<Office> offices = _context.Offices.Include("City");
```

And include City with Province:

```
IQueryable<Office> offices = _context.Offices.Include(o => o.City).ThenInclude(c=>c.Province);
```

My question is, is there any way to ThenInclude province using string parameter? Something like `Include("City.Province")` or `ThenInclude("Province")`.

Comment: You can use Include("City") .ThenInclude("Province").

Comment: @Sergey , Unfortunately there is no `ThenInclude()` overload that takes a parameter as string. And `Include(string nav)` doesn't return `IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, TProperty>` type, it returns `IQueryable<TEntity>` type that we cann't call ThenInclude upon it.

Comment: this one works in EFD6 ,  can work  ef core too -Include("City") .Include("City.Province")

Comment: @Sergey, thanks your right , I was just misleaded by documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
Include("City").Include("City.Province")
```